# How to use lagrange multipliers to find the points on a sphere that are closest to a point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the points on the sphere
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36$ that are closest to and farthest from the point $(1, 2, 2)$.

Based on the solution provided:

$f(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-2)^2$

I don't understand how to represent a point as an equation? Can someone explain how I can turn the point $(1, 2, 2)$ to the equation $f(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-2)^2$?

Lets say if I want to change this question from $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36$ (a sphere) to say a rectangular prism or something, how would this change?

Thanks - Alice

Comment: Can you state the (square of the) distance from point $(x,y,z)$ to the point $(1,2,2)$?

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda)
= \| \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0 \|^2 + 
\lambda
\left( \| \mathbf{x} \|^2 -R^2 \right)
$$
The gradient is
$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
2(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)+2\lambda\mathbf{x}
$.

Setting the gradient to zero
yields the relation
$(\lambda+1)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0$.
and multiplying on the left by $\mathbf{x}^T$
and applying the constraint yields
$
\lambda+1=\frac{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}_0}{R^2}
$.

Thus the stationary points verify
$$
\left(
\frac{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}_0}{R^2}
\right)
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0
$$
Writing $\mathbf{x}= \alpha \mathbf{x}_0$,
we end up with the solution
$
\alpha = \pm R/\|\mathbf{x}_0\|
$
which gives the maxima and minima.